# Unset array key if all array child values are empty

Tags: php, arrays, array-filter

I've an array with the following structure:

```
array(
    "0" => array(
        "0" => array(
            '0' => array('value' => 'value'),
            '1' => array('value' => ''),
            '2' => array('value' => ''),
        ),
        "1" => array(
            '0' => array('value' => 'abc'),
            '1' => array('value' => 'lorem'),
            '2' => array('value' => ''),
        )
    ),
    "1" => array(
        "0" => array(
            '0' => array('value' => ''),
            '1' => array('value' => 'hgjklo'),
            '2' => array('value' => ''),
        ),
        "1" => array(
            '0' => array('value' => 'abcdef'),
            '1' => array('value' => 'value'),
            '2' => array('value' => ''),
        )
    ),
)
```

and what I'm trying to accomplish is to remove all keys for the "empty" value, but only if the value is empty in **all*** child-arrays inside the main-array.

Expected output:

```
array(
    "0" => array(
        "0" => array(
            '0' => array('value' => 'value'),
            '1' => array('value' => ''),
        ),
        "1" => array(
            '0' => array('value' => 'abc'),
            '1' => array('value' => 'lorem'),
        )
    ),
    "1" => array(
        "0" => array(
            '0' => array('value' => ''),
            '1' => array('value' => 'hgjklo'),
        ),
        "1" => array(
            '0' => array('value' => 'abcdef'),
            '1' => array('value' => 'value'),
        )
    ),
)
```

NOTE: child-array position 2 was removed, because it was empty in all the main-array positions.

Does anyone have a great idea how this can be done without a complex logic of foreach's?

Comment: This feels like a job for "not an array of arrays" but a proper data structure?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't go that way... I really need to use arrays.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Have any code? Feels like I am doing your homework.

Comment: Yes, I've tried with a lot of foreach's, but the code became "unredable".  So I was looking for any idea with array_filter or something like that.

Comment: Does your task mean that all array on the deepest level have the same size?

Comment: Yes @Anton , but in the deepest level, besides the "value", key I've another keys but the size of keys is the same in all of them.

Comment: Empty value is always the last one in deepest array? Or it can be on the index 0 for example?

Comment: Yes, it's always the last one, in this specific case the key "value". The index 0, 1, 2 etc, could not be empty! They all follow the same structure, so the only changes will always be on deepest array level!

Comment: `Yes, I've tried with a lot of foreach's, but the code became "unredable"` Show us the code.

Answer (score 0):

As expressed, the structure of the data is not helpful. I agree `array_` functions are generally great, but they work better with structures that make sense.

If for example you removed just a little of the useless cruft, to achieve an array like the following one:

```
$foo = array(
    "0" => array(
        "0" => array(
            '0' => 'value',
            '1' => '',
            '2' => '',
        ),
        "1" => array(
            '0' => 'abc',
            '1' => 'lorem',
            '2' => '',
        )
    ),
    "1" => array(
        "0" => array(
            '0' =>  '',
            '1' => 'hgjklo',
            '2' => ''
        ),
        "1" => array(
            '0' => 'abcdef',
            '1' => 'value',
            '2' => ''
        )
    ),
);
```

You could then do something like:

```
<?php
$uids = array_fill_keys(array_keys($foo[0][0]), 0);

$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($foo));
foreach($it as $k =>$v) {
  if (!empty($v)) $uids[$k]++;
}
var_dump($uids);

/*
The value here shows the number of non empty values in the set per key.
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(3)
  [1]=>
  int(3)
  [2]=>
  int(0)
}
```

Clean the array up more and it just gets easier.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed this could be solution, but besides key "value" I've another keys, and the array cannot be reduced as in your example.